# exec-maven-plugin does not run shell script in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, exec-maven-plugin

hi i try to run a script in my source with the maven exec plugin
It builds and runs just fine on my local machine but on jenkins it does not.

this is the plugin part

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution><!-- Run our version calculation script -->
                    <id>Version Calculation</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>/bin/bash</executable>
                <commandlineArgs>"${session.executionRootDirectory}/update_snapshot_version.sh"</commandlineArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

this is the error

```
16:17:32 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli) on project filters: The parameter 'executable' is missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
16:17:32 [ERROR] 
16:17:32 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
16:17:32 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
16:17:32 [ERROR] 
16:17:32 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

I verified that /bin/bash is existing and the jenkins user has access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the version of the Parent project was wrong in the subproject. Not the most enlightnig errormessage for such a problem though.